# htaccess missing www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /xcrud
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It all works great unless the user skips the `www` as part of the url. Is there a simple way to change this so as to avoid a 310 loop error? A complete example of `.htaccess` would be great and not a 1 liner. thx.

Comment: Are these all of your rewrite rules? There is no evidence here that would cause a rewrite loop based on the HTTP_HOST used.  Do you have some other redirection in place for the www. domain already?

Comment: that is it entirely. what i meant was that since i am a noob any attempts to change this just gets me into loop conditions. so this above does not cause loops but just 404's

Comment: Enable the [RewriteLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and post some of its relevant output please.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot get logging to work at hostgator. it just generates internal server 500 errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved it. I couldn't get any 301 statments to work but this does.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /demo2
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mathpdq\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mathpdq.com/demo2/$1 [R=permanent,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```